# Unable to ping from VM to another VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

I have built two VM, and both use the same network configuration which are NAT for the first network adapter, and Host only Ethernet Adapter for the second adapter.
This is my network configuration for both VM :

First VM
eth0 : dhcp
eth1 : 10.0.0.10 255.255.255.0

Second VM
eth0 : dhcp
eth1 : 10.0.0.20 255.255.255.0

How to solve the problem? should i do or reconfigure something?

Answer (score 0):

In VMWare, Host-Only mean VM's can ONLY network with the host, not other vm's. but in Parallel Desktop and VirtualBox it work.

So in a simple way, if you want to block the network between Second VM and Internet, you could choose NAT and set some firewall with iptable on host.

In VMWare website, you should route between Two Host-Only Networks like this [link](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_advanced_2hostonly_routing.html).

There is more information about [Host Only Network](https://superuser.com/questions/775281/guest-vms-unable-to-ping-each-other-within-a-custom-host-only-network-in-vmware).

Comment: Hello, `Host-only network adapter` in Virtualbox can in fact be used to communicate between `VM's`. You need to have **the same** adapter assigned to each `VM` and they should have separate IP addresses.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, i will try everything. And will come back to ask again.